# DirectX 11: Runtime Assertion Failure using XMLoadFloat4X4()

Tags: c++, debugging, directx-11, assertions

While trying to store matrices inside of a struct, I receive an Assertion Failure error at run-time when calling `XMFLOAT4x4*` types from a struct using `XMLoadFloat4X4()`.

[image]

The values are simply stored as:

```
XMFLOAT4X4 *f4x4_Scale;
XMFLOAT4X4 *f4x4_Rotation;
XMFLOAT4X4 *f4x4_Translate;
XMFLOAT4X4 *f4x4_ObjectViewSpace;
```

Presumably loading the actual values from the `XMFLOAT4x4*` location inside of a struct.

I call `XMLoadFloat4X4()` inside of a transformation function, structure as such:

```
XMMATRIX Entity::Scale(float x, float y, float z){
    XMMATRIX m_Scale = XMLoadFloat4x4(e_Asset.Asset.FileDesc.matrixTransformation.f4x4_Scale);
    m_Scale = XMMatrixScaling(x, y, z);
    return m_Scale;
}
```

The disassembly shows a break inside the `XMLoadFloat4x4()` function itself, but I can't understand it. 
[image]

Is there a way/method I can use to troubleshoot Assertion Failure errors with respect to `XMLoadFloat()`? (Or really good material on Assertion errors) and/or am I doing something wrong?

**Update:**

As Chuck Walbourn suggested, `(XMFLOAT4X4)*pSource` pointer for `XMLoadFloat4X4()` was `NULL`, satisfying the Assert conditions for the function. The pointer being passed was uninitialized at first, then I made an attempt to set the pointer [on the heap].

A watch was set, and the `XMFLOAT4X4` values were initialized to a matrix identity using `XMStoreFloat4X4()`.

```
XMMATRIX Identity = XMMatrixIdentity();
XMStoreFloat4x4(&e_Asset.Asset.FileDesc.matrixTransformation.f4x4_Scale, Identity);
```

The final culprit was just the fact that the transformation functions had so many overloads, and I missed a stray debugging step (I set a new `XMFLOAT4X4` variable in one of the functions and never initialized it) from earlier. The issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DirectXMath is shared source in the library, so you can just step into the function in the debugger.

The only assert in `XMLoadFloat4x4` is to verify the input pointer is not null:

```
/------------------------------------------------------------------------------
_Use_decl_annotations_
inline XMMATRIX XMLoadFloat4x4
(
    const XMFLOAT4X4* pSource
)
{
    assert(pSource);
#if defined(_XM_NO_INTRINSICS_)
```

Do you think the `e_Asset.Asset.FileDesc.matrixTransformation.f4x4_Scale` pointer is actually set here?

Comment: I tried setting the values inside the constructor `Entity(){e_Asset...sformation.f4x4Scale=new XMFLOAT4X4(...)}` (manually input identity matrix). I can try another way though.

Comment: &psource **is** NULL at run-time though.

Comment: Why heap allocate the individual ``XMFLOAT4X4`` instances anyhow? Just put them in your Entity class as value members.

Comment: Good point. That's what I ended up doing.`XMFLOAT4X4 Rotation;`. Initially, I was just putting in the functionality so I can store the `e_Asset` struct in my physics pipeline, but the error caught me off guard. (I thought `Rotation` was filled with an earlier function) I don't know why I chose a heap implement. I think it went that direction due to some strange brain logic - the `const XMFLOAT4X4* pSource` (pointer) made me store in struct as `XMFLOAT4X4*` and my hands just wrote out ...`= new XMF...` A large part of the struct has no prerequisite implementation so in turn, NULL/ not init...

Comment: The original xboxmath library for XBox 360 was written to support compilation by both C and C++. XNAMath had to compile in the same places as xboxmath, so I had to keep it working in C there too for use in the internal Xbox 360 OS software. With DirectXMath I dropped Xbox 360 support and along with it the requirement to support C, but at the same time I didn't want to require all existing clients of XNAMath to have to change drastically to move to DirectXMath. So while ideally it should be ``XMMATRIX XMLoadFloat4x4(const XMFLOAT4X4& source);`` since null is not a valid option, it isn't.